# How to detect device motion direction in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, right-to-left, direction

I am trying to detect the direction in which a device is moved. If a device (mobile or tablet) is picked up and moved to the right or left, I want to detect that using Flutter.

Here is what I've tried:

I have tried using [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) library for this and tried using the accelerometer for detecting left or right direction and the program is given below.

```
void initState() {
userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
  var me = event.x;

  var me2 = num.parse(me.toStringAsFixed(2));
  print(me2);

  if (me2.round() < 0) {
    setState(() {
      direction = "Left";
    });
  }
  if (me2 > 0) {
    if (me2 > 0.5) {
      setState(() {
        direction = "Right";
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        direction = "Still";
      });
    }
  }
});
super.initState();}
```

the outputs I get are:

[image]

The program only shows left or right if I move the device really fast, although I would like to detect the direction on slower speeds. For this, I have tried to take smaller values of `"event.x"` but in that case, the output switches between "Left" and "Right" and "Still" really quickly even when the device is still.

I could not find any example that covers this problem online or in the package docs or examples.

I would like to know how I can achieve this? I would like to know the left and right movement of the device with slow speeds too.

Should I use another sensor?

I do not fully understand the magnetometer's inputs which I've also tried using. Any help in understanding that is appreciated.

I have also tried searching for a package on pub.dev but I can't find any that fit this need.

Any help is appreciated thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you may refer to https://pub.dev/packages/sensors or https://pub.dev/packages/motion_sensors

Answer (score 2):

You can try using location package to access device current location. It has attribute of **heading** which can be useful for you. You can use a listener to capture device location changes. Whenever device heading is changed, the heading value will be printed.

```
Location location = Location();

location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      // Use current location
    print(currentLocation.heading);
});
```

Read more here: https://pub.dev/packages/location

Heading is a double value, that varies from 0 to 360 degrees. [This image will help you to see what heading value means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbjwN.jpg).

Comment: I ran this code, the value of currentlocation.heading remains 90.0 through out. How much should i move my device to see a change in value?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin tells you about *acceleration*. If you want to detect motion, i.e. speed, you need to apply in integration filter to the data from those events. You may want to use `UserAccellerationEvent`s since those already eliminate gravity.

Also, using events from the gyroscope will make you calculation more robust.

This is an application of [*sensor fusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion) by the way.